# compute rate by group

Tags: r, data.table, data-manipulation

I have a data that want to calculate the growth rate by the previous year and quarter.

```
# dt
yq      A        B           
2013 Q1 35233684 270950851
2013 Q2 36235895 274194641
2013 Q3 36767497 275614372
2013 Q4 37273346 277125049
2014 Q1 37788578 278202677
2014 Q2 38674955 281025545

str(dt)
Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame':  6 obs. of  3 variables:
$ yq      : 'yearqtr' num  2013 Q1 2013 Q2 2013 Q3 2013 Q4 ...
$ A   : int  35233684 36235895 36767497 37273346 37788578 38674955
$ B: int  270950851 274194641 275614372 277125049 278202677 281025545
- attr(*, ".internal.selfref")=<externalptr>
```

The code I use:

```
dt[, lapply(.SD, function(x)x/shift(x) - 1), .SDcols = 2:3, by = .(quarter(yq))]
quarter    A          B
1          NA         NA
1          0.07251283 0.02676436
2          NA         NA
2          0.06731060 0.02491261
3          NA         NA
4          NA         NA
```

I got the result; however, I want the format like this:
I want it to keep the column `yq` and order with year and quarter.

```
yq      A        B           
2013 Q1 35233684 270950851
2013 Q2 36235895 274194641
2013 Q3 36767497 275614372
2013 Q4 37273346 277125049
2014 Q1 37788578 278202677
2014 Q2 38674955 281025545

yq      A        B            A_R        B_R
2013 Q1 35233684 270950851    NA         NA
2013 Q2 36235895 274194641    NA         NA
2013 Q3 36767497 275614372    NA         NA
2013 Q4 37273346 277125049    NA         NA
2014 Q1 37788578 278202677    0.07251283 0.02676436
2014 Q2 38674955 281025545    0.06731060 0.02491261
```

How do I do to edit my code?

```
# Data
library(data.table)
dt <- fread("yq      A        B           
2013 Q1 35233684 270950851
2013 Q2 36235895 274194641
2013 Q3 36767497 275614372
2013 Q4 37273346 277125049
2014 Q1 37788578 278202677
2014 Q2 38674955 28102554", header = T)
```

Comment: Could you please provide example data in the form that you're using? The `dt` example data doesn't use the same format for year-qtr as your `dt`.

Comment: `cols <- c("A", "B") ; dt[, paste0(cols, "_R") := .SD / shift(.SD, 4) - 1, .SDcols = cols]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I see you are using the `zoo` package and the function `yearqtr`.  I am unable to get the `yq` column read using your `fread` but I just quickly reproduced the data as follows:

```
library(zoo)
dt<-data.table(cbind(yq=2013 + seq(0,5)/4,
                      A = c(35233684, 36235895, 36767497, 37273346, 37788578, 38674955), 
                      B = c(270950851, 274194641, 275614372, 277125049, 278202677, 281025545)))
```

Then just converted the yq as follows:

```
dt[,yq:=as.yearqtr(yq)]
```

Now if you want to keep that column you will need to update the columns by specifying them:

```
cols<-c("A","B") 
dt[,eval(cols):=lapply(.SD,function(x)x/shift(x) - 1), .SDcols = 2:3, by = .(quarter(yq))]
```

So simply add as many columns as you need to the `cols` vector and use `eval` so `data.table` will not create a new column named "cols"!  Does this answer your question?

Comment: Is it possible to keep original column `A` and `B` without replace them? I modified in my post

Comment: I solved. Just modified a small part. `dt[,eval(c("Anew" , "Bnew"):=lapply(.SD,function(x)x/shift(x) - 1), .SDcols = 2:3, by = .(quarter(yq))]`

Comment: There is no need in `eval`. Both `c()` or just `(cols)` will work

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with `data.table` package. But here is how I would do it using `dplyr`.
You can first separate your `yq` column into two columns, `y` and `q`. I skipped this step in my code because I don't know what exact datatype you used in the original data.
Then group by `q` to do the calculation.

```
library(data.table)
dt <- fread(
"y   q  A        B           
2013 Q1 35233684 270950851
2013 Q2 36235895 274194641
2013 Q3 36767497 275614372
2013 Q4 37273346 277125049
2014 Q1 37788578 278202677
2014 Q2 38674955 281025545", header = T)

library(tidyverse)
dt%>%group_by(q)%>%
     arrange(y)%>%
     mutate(growth_rate_over_year_A= A/lag(A)-1,
            growth_rate_over_year_B= B/lag(B)-1)%>%
    ungroup
```

output:

```
# A tibble: 6 x 6
      y q            A         B growth_rate_over_year_A growth_rate_over_year_B
  <int> <chr>    <int>     <int>                   <dbl>                   <dbl>
1  2013 Q1    35233684 270950851                 NA                      NA     
2  2013 Q2    36235895 274194641                 NA                      NA     
3  2013 Q3    36767497 275614372                 NA                      NA     
4  2013 Q4    37273346 277125049                 NA                      NA     
5  2014 Q1    37788578 278202677                  0.0725                  0.0268
6  2014 Q2    38674955 281025545                  0.0673                  0.0249
```